# when mouseover or out change icon marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

What i want is when user do mouseover (hover) then the icon change. My code is below:

```
handler = Gmaps.build("Google", {
markers: {
  maxRandomDistance: null
}
});
handler.buildMap({
provider: {},
internal: {
  id: "map-canvas"
}
}, function() {
var markers;
markers = handler.addMarkers(ar);
_.each(ar, function(json, index) {
  json.marker = markers[index];
  $(".location-" + json.id).on("mouseover", function() {
    json.picture = {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png",
      width: 36,
      height: 36
    };
    json.marker.setMap(handler.getMap());
    json.marker.panTo();
    handler.removeMarker(json.marker);
    handler.addMarker(json);
  }).on("mouseout", function() {
    json.picture = '';
    handler.removeMarker(json.marker);
    handler.addMarker(json);
  });
});
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

Using this code, the color of the marker can change from red to green. However, when the user remove their mouse from the hover area, the color does not change back to the original color. Please can anyone suggest me on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: what if you replace `json.picture = ''` with `delete json.picture`

Comment: @apneadiving can you suggest me about hover code from hovering div element?

the example is https://www.airbnb.com/s/Barcelona--Spain. when hovering place the map icon change color to blue

Answer (score 1):

Hai thank for @apneadiving answer. I modify my code to this

```
hoverPicture = {
url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png",
width: 33,
height: 33
};
handler = Gmaps.build("Google", {
markers: {
  maxRandomDistance: null
}
});
handler.buildMap({
provider: {},
internal: {
  id: "map-canvas"
}
}, function() {
var markers;
markers = handler.addMarkers(ar);
_.each(ar, function(json, index) {
  var gr;
  json.marker = markers[index];
  gr = {};
  gr.marker = void 0;
  $(".location-" + json.id).on("mouseover", function() {
    gr = {
      lat: json.lat,
      lng: json.lng,
      picture: hoverPicture
    };
    json.marker.panTo();
    handler.removeMarker(json.marker);
    gr.marker = handler.addMarker(gr);
  }).on("mouseout", function() {
    handler.removeMarker(gr.marker);
    json.marker = handler.addMarker(json);
  });
});
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

So the new icon need to insert to variable after addMarker

Comment: This works. I think the key is this line `gr.marker = handler.addMarker(gr);` So when you're removing the marker on `mouseout` you're targeting what you added.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
_.each(ar, function(json, index) {

  var json.marker = markers[index];
  var initialPicture = json.picture;
  var hoverPicture = {
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png",
    width: 36,
    height: 36
  }

  $(".location-" + json.id).on("mouseover", function() {
    json.picture = hoverPicture;
    json.marker.setMap(handler.getMap());
    json.marker.panTo();
    handler.removeMarker(json.marker);
    handler.addMarker(json);
  }).on("mouseout", function() {
    json.picture = initialPicture;
    handler.removeMarker(json.marker);
    var newMarker = handler.addMarker(json);
    json.marker = newMarker;
  });
});
```

Comment: not working. is there any syntax like handler.setIcons({picture:"green.png"}) or handler.setIcons({fillcolor:"green"})?

Comment: fillColor is not an option of google map markers so no. Could you show what the generated html?

Comment: This is returning an error `var json.marker = markers[index];`